# Best practice for background image

Tags: css, background

I have a large background image that I am trying to make work. I have it positioned using CSS and it seems fine in everything but IE. For some reason in all version of IE I have tested it leaves a large white gap at the bottom.

I was wondering if there was a best practice I was not aware of.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

The image is 2500px X 1500px

```
body
{
margin:0px;
background-image: url(../img/main_bg_2.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center; 
}
```

I have tried this approach which works too, but the image fills about 700px down than the rest is white on all browsers.

```
body
{
margin:0px;
background-image: url(../img/main_bg_2.jpg);
background-size:100%,100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: What version IE are you using

Answer (score 6):

If your priority is for the image to hit every corner (and you don't mind cropping the image), try the following, taken from [Chris Coyier's CSS Tricks site](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/):

```
html { 
    background: url(../img/main_bg_2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    /* IE */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/main_bg_2.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/main_bg_2.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this approach seemed to work best.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
html {height:100%}
```

I think that was the issue with IE... that the body can be 100% but the height isn't 100% by default... so you can override it.

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a common reset alot of developers use.

```
*  {
   margin: 0;
  }
```

If it is a particular IE version you can use this.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for use a background with an image depends :

a) If you need to show a only color or degrade image, the best practice is to create a small image and repeat the image in the page.

b) If you need to show a large image, you will need to low the quality of the image. (JPEG format is smaller than PNG)

c) Sometimes you could use the fixed the image. for example :

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Regards.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I will review more closely.